# Tkinter Optionmenu: Command with an input argument next to "value"

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to use an optionmenu as follows:

```
myStVar = tk.StringVar()
self.myOm = ttk.Optionmenu(self.master, myStVar, "Text", *options, command = self.foo(?????) )
```

with:

```
def foo(self, value, in)
   print(str(value) + " " + "str(in))
```

How does the `command: self.foo()` have to look like for this to work? Usually, with

```
def foo(self, value)
   print(str(value))
```

works. But with an additional variable I am puzzled.

I apologize if this is a duplicate, I haven't found it, though.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you want to pass as `in`? Usually you would use a `lambda` function to passe extra arguments in the command.

Comment: an `np.array` - how would that look like using `lambda`?

Comment: Something like `command=lambda value: self.foo(value, array)`, in which you replace `array` with the actual name of the `np.array` object.

Comment: Thank you! This works. It seems like I have to read up on lambda - currently I just use it to prevent a function from getting called at initialisation

Comment: What you need to remember is that the `command` argument expects a function reference, therefore you can not use something like `command=function(x)`. This will save the return value of `function(x)` as the command instead of running `function(x)` as the command. In this case, lambda functions are useful because they create a reference to an anonymous function that passes arguments to another function.

Comment: I see. Hypothetically - would `command = foo(x)` work if `foo(x)` itself created a function? Like with a function template?